# I want to restrict the dimensions of images users can select with a JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I have a JFileChooser that lets users choose an image for themselves. I want to limit the images they can choose to ones with square dimensions, for example -

width and height both 50

width and height both 75, etc...

So when they select an image with the JFileChooser and click 'Open' I need to validate the image size and if it doesn't have square dimensions I need to present the user with a dialog informing them "The image must have the same width and height".

I'm just learning swing so I don't know how to do this. Any ideas on how to do this? Is there a way of hooking the "Open" button's event handler?

Comment: What if you scale the image selected by the user, manually to your desired width and height instead of telling user to do that. Won't that scenario work ?

Comment: I dont want to have to crop or pad it, that is more work than required and it will lead to black borders if the images arent square. I have to have square images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can *hide* all images that do not confirm to the rules with an implementation of a `FileFilter`:

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser(new File(filename));
fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new MyFilter());

// Open file dialog.
fileChooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
openFile(fileChooser.getSelectedFile());

class MyFilter extends javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter {
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        // load the image
        // check if it satisfies the criteria
        // return boolean result
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers mate, that could work but then the problem is users wont be seeing many images. I need them to be able to see all their images as they would on any image upload system, yet when they try to select it in my application they will be informed of the size requirements. In which case they will open paint or photoshop and edit the image. So I cant just hide all the images.

Comment: I just have a feeling that it must be possible to intercept the mouse click on the "Open" button before the JFileChooser performs whatever actions it performs and closes the dialog. Anyone know if it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

I tried overwriting

```
public void approveSelection ()
```

by deriving a own class from JFileChooser, and at first glance, it seemed to work.

The method is called, I can make a test on the selected file, and, if it fails, recall `showOpenDialog (ref);`.

#### But ...

It works fine, when I call a legitimate file, and it opens a new dialog, if not, but after that, the dialog won't close again normally, and if forced by the X of the window, I get a StackTrace printed. So I guess the state of the dialog is the critical thing here - it doesn't work if 'showOpenDialog' is called recursively.

Here is one of the variants I tested:

```
class ProportionalImageChooser extends JFileChooser
{
    private Component ref;
    
    public ProportionalImageChooser (File f)
    {
        super (f);
    }
    
    public int showOpenDialog (Component parent) 
    {
        ref = parent;
        return super.showOpenDialog (parent);
    }

    public void approveSelection () {
        System.out.println ("approving selection!");
        String fname = getSelectedFile ().getName (); 
        if (fname.matches (".*e.*")) {
            cancelSelection ();
            System.out.println ("Dialog: size doesn't match");
            showOpenDialog (ref);
        }
        else super.approveSelection ();
    }
}
```

To keep the test simple, I only tested the filename to include an 'e' or not.

So I suggest, use Boris' approach, and test your file after finishing the dialog. If it fails, immediately reopen a new one.